# Basic android watch face app not appearing on real device

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api

I tried building watch face sample for Android Wear watch face.
It works on emulator, but it doesn't appear on real watch.
I tried signing package and installing via phone, but again no success.

Comment: Do you mean you tried building the watch face sample that is on our GitHub repo and you ran into issue on a real watch, or you meant you wrote your own watch face sample and you ran into issue with that? For the former, I just tried the existing sample and worked fine on both the emulator and a real watch. If the latter, then you are providing zero information so we can't really help you with your sample, I suggest you take a look at our sample (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace) and see if that works for you and if it does, see where yours is different

Comment: I just used template sample in Android Studio, while creating new project.

Comment: I just tried that as well, I didn't make any changes to what Android Studio created and ran that successfully on both an emulator and a real watch. Make sure you look carefully among the watch faces on the real watch when you look for that one, do a long press and swipe through all of them till you find the right one.

Comment: I hard resetted device, now it's working properly :|